# Any idea how to remove read only attribute in created folder by batch script mkdir folder?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

```
@echo off  
md folder1   
attrib -s -h -r "folder1" /s /d 
dir c:\windows>>text.txt  
attrib -s -h - r  text.txt  
pause
```

Created by simple command `md folder1` and in 3rd line I follow advice from

[How to remove read-only attribute recursively on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/653951/how-to-remove-read-only-attribute-recursively-on-windows-7folder)

This should help  to  remove attributes **[-h],[-s],[-r]** with added additional parameters **/s & /d** to be sure that this will works for folders too.

Everything is  working well with  file and folders working only with switches **[-h],[-s]** but   so far I can't find a  way to **remove/change [-r] read-only** attribute for any folders or subfolders.

Is there any way to change attributes read-only in folders using  batch script or cmd ? 
(*even if batch is started with admin rights this no change*)

What is reason that switch read-only **[-r]** for empty created folders not working?

---

**Is this Windows Enviroment protection not allow to change folder's [-r] attribute?**

Comment: See if this helps: https://superuser.com/questions/653951/how-to-remove-read-only-attribute-recursively-on-windows-7

Comment: Yes, You right- I removed batch & linux tags

Comment: Thanks for link                                                                                                       I checked if it works in this  related topic link .with many answers                 I tried to open  cmd with admin rights and typed :attrib /? - Displays or changes file attributes. for items displays.One of most interesting in my question is switch with ...... "/D  it means " Processes folders as well." So I can easily use this 3rd line of my code and add switch" /d "      attrib +h - r folder1 /d- It doesn't make any difference attribute read-only remains unchanged.

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut Would u be so kind and tell me how to highlight background of code- I'm beginer and  I was trying but couldn't find   and have not to much time for that?

Comment: Hope this helps https://superuser.com/editing-help , for code markup, either give 4 spaces at the beginning of the line or enclose your code within `` (backticks)

Comment: 'Thanks- I will follow  to improve that.!'